# WordPress Gutenberg How to make TextControl Required?

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I want to make this field required. Can anyone suggest how to do it?

```
<TextControl
    tagName="p"
    label="url"
    placeholder="http://"
    focus = {focus}
    className="full-width "
    value={ props.attributes.url }
    onChange={ onChangeurl }
    keepPlaceholderOnFocus= {true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could possibly done using [lockPostSaving](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/10649)

Some code example ➡ https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/16713